# Where is image/video data stored while being processed by a backend script?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, upload

I'm designing a web app where users can upload videos to be processed/formatted, then saved and made available to download. I plan to host the app on an AWS EC2 instance and use an s3 bucket for long-term storage of finished videos. I'm wondering where the video data will be stored on the backend machine during the time it is being actively worked on.

My concern is that, if the video data is loaded into RAM even just for the duration it's being processed, that an unreasonably small number of simultaneous users will quickly overload the available memory of the EC2 instance.

Am I wrong in thinking that the video data must be loaded into memory to be modified by a script? Is there a better way to structure this so that the server can accommodate more users simultaneously?

Comment: Where do you process those videos?

Comment: Planning on sending them from a client webpage to a Node.js server in an HTTP request, then running the processing script on the same EC2 instance serving the webpage.

Comment: Maybe post your code that takes the image so we can see if you're doing any code magic.

Comment: What type of "processing" will you be doing? If it is simple transcoding, then the Amazon Elastic Transcoder can do it for you. Or are you doing fancy stuff on top of the videos, like Vine?

Comment: Sorry should have specified that. The processing is more than simple transcoding. Similarly to what you said, the app will automatically crop videos to a standard size and add colored borders and captions or other decoration elements. I was considering using ImageMagick or some equivalent library for videos.

Comment: @Slipoch, I haven't written the code yet, I'm trying to figure out where the code should live vs. the data received.

Comment: I guess that's up to you, you could put it into blob storage on a db, or you could use a filesystem save or something like that. I would avoid using RAM due to the reasons you have given.

Comment: @Slipoch But files can't be directly modified while in disk storage, they'll need to be moved to RAM in the meantime while they're being modified, correct? My question is if it's feasible to process videos on the same server hosting the app, due to concerns of limited memory size.

Comment: You could load each frame or group of frames from the file into RAM separately as you process the file, then save as you go, that way if there is an error you will have up to the point of failure and can auto-retry.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using AWS MediaConvert for this project as a solution.
AWS Elemental MediaConvert is a file-based video processing service that allows video providers with any size content library to easily and reliably transcode on-demand content for broadcast and multiscreen delivery. Used as a standalone service or integrated with other AWS Media Services, AWS Elemental MediaConvert lets you build flexible file-based video workflows with full control over video quality and predictable pay-as-you-go billing.

Comment: Not sure if this is what I'm looking for, the app will add colored captions and borders to videos so it's more graphical manipulation than transcoding.